# USB Drive not recognized under /dev

Tags: linux, usb, centos, dev

I was reading/learning about partitioning, creating file-system, etc.
and wanted to do some practical.
 So i booted my CentOS installed on my windows laptop using Virtual Box and inserted a blank usb into the computer; i was expecting a new device node inserted inside /dev but count returned:-
 from `ls -l /dev/ | wc -l` is same before & after inserting the usb.
 I also rebooted the vm but the count was still same.

Comment: Did you pass through the usb stick from your host to guest in the Virtualbox VM settings?

Comment: In vm settings under usb settings i have enabled usb controller, also i havent set any usb device filters. Not sure if i answered your question.

Comment: No, you need to do one more thing. In the window of your running VM, go the Devices menu option on top. Then go to USB and select your usb stick. If you don't see your usb stick listed, you will need to install Guest Additions in CentOS if you haven't already done that.

Comment: Any device that you plug into your physical machine will not appear on your guest until you explicitly pass it through.

Comment: @n8te: Please post this in the answer form below.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Virtual Box you have to install guest services or under devices check if the usb stick is listed there. 
you can also check in dmesg (kernel messages) if the usb stick was recognized there.